# Multi-line alert in Javascript

Tags: javascript, alert

This code

```js
alert("Hello again! This is how we" + "\n" + "add line breaks to an alert box!");
```

doesn't work.
Firefox JavaScript console names error as "unterminated string literal" and points on " symbol before \n.
I want to fire an alert with multi-line text. No jQuery please.

Comment: The offending code is not that piece of code. Note that the syntaxerror messages are almost always misleading

Comment: when i add // before this line everything works fine

Comment: Nevertheless, if you run that code in isolation, it will work normally, I just tested it. Please provide more code.

Comment: This alert fires in function
function FCKeditor_OnComplete( editorInstance ) {  
  
        alert("Hello again! This is how we"+String.fromCharCode(10)+"add line breaks to an alert box!");

Comment: That function is missing `}` but works fine after adding it

Comment: It's not the problem, but `"\n"` doesn't need to be separate, just say `"...how we\nadd line..."`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Haven't tested but does this work?

```
alert("Hello again! This is how we \n add line breaks to an alert box!");
```

Answer (score 25):

This just happened to me... exactly.  I needed to change it to `\\n` instead of `\n`.

```
alert("Hello again! This is how we"+"\\n"+"add line breaks to an alert box!");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is correct when all the javascript code comes from server side as a string, example: "alert('Hello again! This is how we'+'\\n'+'add line breaks to an alert box!');";    --> with \\n line break works, otherwise fails.

Comment: Nope, \n alone is correct. If you put it into another string (like when you make an echo "alert('x\ny');";), the result would be an alert('x[linebreak]y');, which is incorrect. You have to double escape it with \\n, yes, but this has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 7):

Question is old but I want to give a clear answer and explain why this happens for others who comes here:

First of all, there is nothing wrong with the JavaScript code line in the question. It is absolutely valid and produces no parsing error. The reason for the problem in Vitalmax' case was most likely because he/she didn't posted additional code, which surrounded that line.

Here is an example in PHP, which shows why the JS parser complains about the syntax:

```
<?php
  echo "alert('Hello again! This is how we\nadd line breaks to an alert box!');";
?>
```

The parsed server-side output then is (this is what the browser gets):

```
alert("Hello again! This is how we
add line breaks to an alert box!");
```

In JavaScript, strings **must not** have real line breaks.* Instead, they must always be escaped (like: \n), so the browser complains about an "unterminated string literal" at the real line break. There are some exceptions to this rule, like for horizontal tabulators (\t). So (in this case) you have to escape the line breaks twice with \\n. So when PHP parses and converts it from \\n to \n, JavaScript can convert it from \n to *[real line break]*.

Correct PHP example would be:

```
<?php
  echo "alert('Hello again! This is how we\\nadd line breaks to an alert box!');";
?>
```

Or:

```
<?php
  echo 'alert("Hello again! This is how we\nadd line breaks to an alert box!");';
?>
```

In the second case you don't have to double escape it because escaped characters within PHP strings with single quotes are not decoded (\n stays \n).

*Note: It is possible to use the special quote sign ` which allows real line breaks in JS. Example:

```
alert(`Hello again! This is how we
add line breaks to an alert box!`);
```

Comment: Added note for special string encapsulation chars (`), which support real line breaks.

Answer (score 6):

Adding changing `\n` to `\\n` should work if you are rendering the alert serverside (ie: On a website), but if you are running client side (ie: testing etc.) just `\\n` will not work work. For example, try running the following lines on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/) website.

```
alert("Hello again! This is how we"+"\n"+"add line breaks to an alert box!");
```

or:

```
 alert("Hello again! This is how we" +"\\n" +"add line breaks to an alert box!");
```

In jsfiddle, the first one works, because it runs it client side, but if you are running it serverside, it requires the double slash (`\\n`) I'm not sure why this is, but I have tested it multiple times.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`error "missing ; before statement"`
That tells me the semicolon is missing from above this line of code. Usual syntax gotchya are if statements that don't close parentheses properly. Or curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
alert("Hello. \n How are you?")
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

This script works for me.

```
<script>
  alert("Hello. \r\n How are you?");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes.

```
alert("Hello again! This is how we"+'\n'+"add line breaks to an alert box!");
```

Answer (score 0):

A more functional way i would suggest is to define your own `print()` function and forget about putting `\\n` for each line manually

```js
//define
var print = new Function("var lines=arguments[0]+'\\n';; for(var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++){lines+=arguments[i]+'\\n';} alert(lines);");
    
//call
print("say","hello","to","javascript","this","is ","awesome");
```

Now you may call the `print()` with multiple arguments and each argument will be available in a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `String.fromCharCode()`:

```
alert("This unit has been removed from stock" + String.fromCharCode(13) + " Do you wish to RETURN this unit to stock?");
```

Answer (score 0):

alert("Hello again! This is how we" + "\n" + "add line breaks to an alert box!");

\n --> this is working
[working with \n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoQhV.png)

\n --> does not work, it just treat it as continuous string of alert msges
[does not working with \n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmMVi.png)

Comment: It is no quite clear with your formatting what you mean, you could wrap your code inside a JavaScript snippet as examples (as the author have done in the question) to make it easier for people to understand what the differences are.

Comment: thanks @Johan, actually i am totally new to stack overflow and i was trying to insert output images to make difference between the two things which i tried to explain but fail to do so. but now am aware about how to use snippet. thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, it's a great initiative to share your solutions!

Answer (score 0):

I had issues where \n and \n didn't work, then I tried using html break tag i.e. 
 since that panel was written in html and it worked.

example -

```
some text here <br> some more text
```

output:

```
some text here
some more text
```