# Add multi-line jquery alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to concatenate a string to display in a jquery `alert`. I've followed the instructions, which seem pretty basic, on posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340223/multi-line-alert-in-javascript), however I'm not having any luck.

For example, this jquery code

```
    //Validate field values
    var errors = "";
    if (inputArray[0].length != 8) {
        errors += "Life Master must be 8 digits"+'\\n';
    }
    if (inputArray[1].length != 3) {
        errors += "Market Segment must be 3 digist" + '\\n';
    }
    if (ValidateDate(inputArray[3])) {
        errors += "Invalid Effective Date" + '\\n';
    }
    if (ValidateDate(inputArray[4])) {
        errors += "Invalid Cancel Date";
    }

    if (errors != "") {
        errors = "Please check the following:" + '\\n' + errors;
        alert(errors);
        return false;
    }
```

creates an alert that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: because you are escaping the \ you just need `\n`, also you do not need to use it in a separate string: `"Invalid Effective Date \n"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841452/new-line-in-javascript-alert-box

Comment: and this is not a jQuery alert, that is just the native browser alert function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `\n` not `\\n`

like `alert('one\ntwo')`

Answer (score 1):

\n is newline

by calling \\ you are escaping \ therefore asking browser to print \n not line break

Answer (score 1):

As others have you mentioned, you are escaping the first "\". One stylistic consideration you may want to make is to use an array that holds all of the error messages. Check if you have any errors and then join the array elements with the newline and alert the error messages.

Here is a working example that should get the point across.

[jsfiddle](http://goo.gl/qUPizx)